# Почему в список добавляються несколько значений, но должно добавляться одно?

Tags: python, функции, списки

```
def ruh(q, dic ):
    if q == "выход" :
        return 'выход'
    elif q not in dic:
        print('Ошибка ввода. Попробуйте снова.')
    elif q in dic:
        a = dic[q]
        grosi.append(a[1])


#________________________________________________________________

def rut(q, dic ):
    if q not in dic:
        print('Ошибка ввода. Попробуйте снова.')
    elif q in dic:
        a = dic[q]
        grosi.append(a[1])
        list.append(a[0])
        return 1    

#______________________________________________________________________                     

def zak(list, grosi):
    print('Ваш заказ:')
    for n in list2:
        print(n)
    p = sum(grosi)
    print('С вас:' + str(p)+'грн')

#_________________________________________________________________________

def nap(dic):
    for ky, n in dic.items():
        str(n[1])
        print('\t' + ky + ' : ' + n[0] + ' - ' + str(n[1])+'грн.' )

#_________________________________________________________________

list = []   

flag = True     

grosi = [ ]

dic = {'1' : ['Маленькая' , 20] , '2' : ['Стандарт', 25] , '3' : ['Большая', 30]} 
dic2 = {'1' : ['Обычный', 0], '2' : ['Сырный', 3]}
dic3 = {'1' : ['Грибы' ,  3] , '2' : ['Сыр' , 2] , '3' : ['Картошка', 2] , '4' : ['Маслины' , 2] }

#___________________________________________________________________

print("---------------------------------")
print("Заказ шавухи")
print("---------------------------------")

print("Выбирете размер шавухи:")
nap(dic)

while True:
    q = str(input(" "))
    rut(q, dic )
    if rut(q, dic) == 1:
        break

print (list)

print("\nВыбирете лаваш:")
nap(dic2)

while True:
    q = str(input(" "))
    rut(q, dic2)
    if rut(q, dic) == 1:
        break

print (list)

while True:
    s = str(input('\nС острым соусом?' + '\n\t1 : да ' + '\n\t2 : нет' + '\n'))
    if s == '1':
        list.append("Острая")
        break
    elif s != '2':
        print('Ошибка ввода. Попробуйте снова.')

print (list)
```

[image: Вот что получается. Что я сделал не так?]

Answer (score 0):

Потому что вы функции вызываете по 2 раза. Попробуйте так

```
....
while True:
    q = str(input(" "))
    if rut(q, dic) == 1:
        break

print(list)

print("\nВыбирете лаваш:")

nap(dic2)

while True:
    q = str(input(" "))
    if rut(q, dic) == 1:
        break

print(list)
....
```